# Has anyone been able to use elasticsearch xpack sql with Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Using PySpark I'm trying to read data from elasticsearch. Normally I would set the query to something along the line (see query below) and set the es.resource to index such as "my_index/doc" and I'm able to read data into spark:

```
q ="""{
          "query": {
              "match_all": {}
          }  
      }"""
```

However recently I've tried _xpack/sql with kibana and JDBC with other SQL clients and they work very well to get data. However when I try and reference _xpack in my pyspark code I get the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling 
z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.newAPIHadoopRDD.
: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopInvalidRequest: 
org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopRemoteException: 
invalid_index_name_exception: Invalid index name [_xpack], must not start with '_'.
null
```

Has anyone tried using _xpack or knows how to execute Elasticsearch SQL queries from Elasticsearch hadoop plugin?

Below you'll find an excerpt of my code that I'm trying to use to execute over pyspark, thanks in advance!

```
q = """{"query": "select * from eg_flight limit 1"}"""

es_read_conf = {
    "es.nodes" : "192.168.1.71,192.168.1.72,192.168.1.73",
    "es.port" : "9200",
    "es.resource" :  "_xpack/sql",
    "es.query" : q
}

es_rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
    inputFormatClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsInputFormat",
    keyClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable", 
    valueClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.LinkedMapWritable", 
    conf=es_read_conf)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this feature is supported. An alternative solution in PySpark would have been to use the JDBC driver, which I did try. I tried the following:

```
es_df = spark.read.jdbc(url="jdbc:es://http://192.168.1.71:9200", table = "(select * from eg_flight) mytable")
```

and I got the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o2488.jdbc.
: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Found 1 problem(s)
line 1:8: Unexecutable item

...
```

An alternative would be to do it using core Python and request as such but it I won't recommend it for large datasets.

```
import requests as r
import json


es_template = {
    "query": "select * from eg_flight"
}

es_link = "http://192.168.1.71:9200/_xpack/sql"
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}


if __name__ == "__main__":

    load = r.post(es_link, data=json.dumps(es_template), headers=headers)
    if load.status_code == 200:
        load = load.json()
        #do something with it
```